# Most elegant way to format multi-line strings in Python

Tags: python, string, coding-style, formatting

I have a multiline string, where I want to change certain parts of it with my own variables. I don't really like piecing together the same text using `+` operator. Is there a better alternative to this?

For example (internal quotes are necessary):

```
line = """Hi my name is "{0}".
I am from "{1}".
You must be "{2}"."""
```

I want to be able to use this multiple times to form a larger string, which will look like this:

```
Hi my name is "Joan".
I am from "USA".
You must be "Victor".

Hi my name is "Victor".
I am from "Russia".
You must be "Joan".
```

Is there a way to do something like:

```
txt == ""
for ...:
    txt += line.format(name, country, otherName)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
info = [['ian','NYC','dan'],['dan','NYC','ian']]
>>> for each in info:
    line.format(*each)


'Hi my name is "ian".\nI am from "NYC".\nYou must be "dan".'
'Hi my name is "dan".\nI am from "NYC".\nYou must be "ian".'
```

The star operator will unpack the list into the `format` method.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to a list, you can also use a dictionary. This is useful if you have many variables to keep track of at once.

```
text = """\
Hi my name is "{person_name}"
I am from "{location}"
You must be "{person_met}"\
"""
person = {'person_name': 'Joan', 'location': 'USA', 'person_met': 'Victor'}

print text.format(**person)
```

Note, I typed the text differently because it lets me line up the text easier. You have to add a '\' at the beginning """ and before the end """ though.

Now if you have several dictionaries in a list you can easily do

```
people = [{'person_name': 'Joan', 'location': 'USA', 'person_met': 'Victor'},
          {'person_name': 'Victor', 'location': 'Russia', 'person_met': 'Joan'}]

alltext = ""
for person in people:
  alltext += text.format(**person)
```

or using list comprehensions

```
alltext = [text.format(**person) for person in people]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
line = """Hi my name is "{0}".
I am from "{1}".
You must be "{2}"."""

tus = (("Joan","USA","Victor"),
       ("Victor","Russia","Joan"))

lf = line.format # <=== wit, direct access to the right method

print '\n\n'.join(lf(*tu) for tu in tus)
```

result

```
Hi my name is "Joan".
I am from "USA".
You must be "Victor".

Hi my name is "Victor".
I am from "Russia".
You must be "Joan".
```